# How can we get Position of an image and place an other image on that position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I want to know how can we get exact position of an image and place an other image on that position

excepted positions are
top left, top center, top right
left center, center, right center
bottom left, bottom center, bottom right

For example I have a main image now I put another image on its bottom center.

Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

User `.offset()` method to get the position of image. Explicitly use `.offset().top` or `.offset().left` to get top left coordinate. use `.width()` and `.height()` to get width and height of elements. Do some highschool maths and here you go. Voila you get the right answer.

Comment: this one is pretty easy. If written correct code, your page will work for every browser dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with `getBoundingClientRect()`.

```
var foo = bar.getBoundingClientRect();
```

You can set position of something dynamically using the returned variable foo.

```
foo.left, foo.right, etc.
```

[Mdn for the api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 0):

Please try **.position()** function. The **.position()** method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent.

```
 var div = $( "div ");
 var position = div.position();
 alert("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
```